# Proper clearance for a thermowell in pipe T

Tags: plumbing, copper

I have temperature gauge that uses a thermowell to insert into a pipe. It is 1/2" in diameter and I was hoping to use copper tee to install it. However, looking at the well after it's inserted into the 3/4" pipe has me concerned about affect on flow though the pipe. Unfortunately there are no guidelines on the product sheet. What guidelines should I adhere to for installing the thermometer's thermowell?

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the part extends past the 1/2" portion of the tee and into the 3/4" portion? How much?

Comment: I can add a picture.

Comment: It is literally a 1/2" brass column that extends more than half way into a 3/4" pipe.

Comment: What are you using this for? How accurate does it need to be? You might be fine inserting it only to the point it's flush with the larger-diameter portion of the tee, because the copper itself is a pretty good heat conductor. You could mock this up and test it before a permanent install if you're concerned.